# Deriving an approximation for the Riemann zeta function

Tags: approximation, riemann-zeta

By analyzing the graph of the function $\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)$ I've noticed a circular shape for $-3.3<t<3.3$ as shown below.

[image]

Based on that, an approximation for such function on the mentioned interval is
$$\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right) \approx -\left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) +\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{it}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Is there a way to derive such approximation algebraically from the analytic continued equation of the Riemann zeta function?

Comment: See http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/zetaevaluations.pdf at the bottom of page 5

Comment: The _track_ of $\zeta(\frac12+it)$ aligns reasonably well with the circle, but it doesn't move at constant _speed_ along it like your proposed approximation does. So it's off by more than immediately visible on the plot.